# Handle promise resolves indvidually in promise.all()

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird, progress

There is a lot of information on how to handle errors when using `promise.all()` using `catch` but what I'm trying to achieve is to handle every time a promise inside of this `promise.all()` resolves. The reason I'm trying to do this is because I am attempting to setup a custom progress bar in console and I need to call the tick method every time a promise is resolved.

```
this.getNewSources = function () {
    var bar = new ProgressBar(':bar', {total: this.getSourceMap().size});
    var timer = setInterval(function () {
        bar.tick();
        if (bar.complete) {
            console.log('\ncomplete\n');
            clearInterval(timer);
        }
    }, 100);

    let promiseArr = [];
    for (let x of this.getSourceMap().values()) {
        promiseArr.push(this.requestArticles(x.getName(), x.getCat(), x.getKey()));
    }

    return Promise.all(promiseArr).then(() => {
        console.log("Articles loaded this round: " + this.articles.size);
        console.log('all sources updated');
        this.loadedArticles = true;
        console.log(this.articleCount);
        console.log(this.articles.size);
    }).catch(e => {
        console.log(e);
    });
};
```

I'm trying to figure out a way of being able to call the `bar.tick()` method when each individual promise resolves.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thank you so much for answering, I'm pretty sure I wouldn't of gotten to that answer without what you originally explained.

Comment: My pleasure. :-) Tell you what: I'll post a new answer with the explanation. Grab whatever you need when posting your answer, and ping me to delete mine when you're done. I'm happy just doing the assist. :-)

Comment: Sounds like a great idea! :D I'm still trying to glue this into the original function though I'm not so fast at getting it all figured out.

Comment: No worries. Happy coding!

Comment: updated with the full working code, works perfectly. Will update with a gif example soon!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*(Answering my own question.)*

I handled it by adding a `then` handler where I'm getting the promise from `requestArticles` (where I'm pushing them into the `promiseArr` array). I had to be sure to pass the value that handler receives out of the handler so it propagates to `Promise.all`, see `***` lines:

```
 this.getNewSources = function () {
    var bar = new ProgressBar(':bar', {total: this.getSourceMap().size});
    var timer = setInterval(function () {
        if (bar.complete) {
            console.log('\ncomplete\n');
            clearInterval(timer);
        }
    }, 100);

    function updateProgressBar() {
        bar.tick()
    }

    let promiseArr = [];
    for (let x of this.getSourceMap().values()) {
        promiseArr.push(this.requestArticles(x.getName(), x.getCat(), x.getKey())
            .then(value => {           // ***
                updateProgressBar();   // ***
                return value;          // ***
            })                         // ***
        );
    }

    return Promise.all(promiseArr).then(() => {
        console.log("Articles loaded this round: " + this.articles.size);
        console.log('all sources updated');
        this.loadedArticles = true;
        console.log(this.articleCount);
        console.log(this.articles.size);
    }).catch(e => {
        console.log(e);
    });
};
```

That way, my handlers get called as the promises complete individually, and since I'm returning the value I receive, the promise created by my call to `then` will resolve with that value, which `Promise.all` will see. Rejections will skip over that handler and go straight to the handlers hooked up by `Promise.all`.

[The ascii progress library on npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/progress)

Result output in console:

[image: console loading bar]

---

*(With thanks to [T.J. Crowder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157247/t-j-crowder) for his initial explanation, which made me realize I could do this where I'm pushing onto the array. He said he preferred deleting that answer and having me post this instead.)*

Comment: Much better looking! Just going to add the gif and link to the progress library in case anyone is interested.

Comment: It's absolutely fine that it didn't. :-) (Sorry, I didn't notice you'd added that, and SO didn't warn me when I hit save. Be careful with links like that, sometimes people consider them self-promotion.)